# jQuery AJAX PUT request data submission not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, put

I have a PHP file which contains the following:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'PUT') {
    echo '{ "response": "' . $_REQUEST['id'] . '" }';
}
```

Now I want to make an AJAX call to this file via jQuery:

```
var send = {
    id: 10
};

$.ajax({
    data: send,
    method: 'PUT',
    url: "myphpfile.php",
    success: function(responseData) {
        console.log(responseData.response);
    }
});
```

This should return `10` as a response, however the output is empty. In the PHP file I also tried writing the id to a text file, which turned out to be empty as well. This means that my PHP code isn't the problem here, it's JavaScript.

When I change the AJAX url to `myphpfile.php?id=10` however, the response is correct and `10` is logged to the console.

I have tried a lot of things to fix this, nothing worked. This includes setting `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`, `dataType: 'json'` and `data: JSON.stringify(send)`. I can't find any more forum questions or articles on this and the ones I found didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you try to add a callback function for ajax response to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Have you tried just console.log(responseData) ?   The response that you are receiving may simply be text.  Thus, responseData.response won't show any value.

Comment: Is PHP reporting any errors? Check http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php you may not be able to use `$_REQUEST` for this

Comment: Are you sure you dont want `method: 'GET'`?  *When I change the AJAX url to myphpfile.php?id=10 however, the response is correct and 10 is logged to the console.* That's likely because your PHP is looking for a $_GET variable

Comment: @Craig It returns `Object {response: ""}`. Even if I set `dataType: 'text'`, it returns no id: `{ "response": "" }`

Comment: @DelightedD0D I am trying to create a RESTful API, `POST` and `GET` are used for something else

Comment: Ahh, see this post http://lornajane.net/posts/2008/accessing-incoming-put-data-from-php

Comment: As @DelightedD0D mentioned, you can't access PUT data from the $_REQUEST super variable. You will need to get a look into referred link to access PUT Data.

Comment: Thank you, @apokryfosm, @DelightedD0D and @Alexis Côté! Apparently, `$_REQUEST` doesn't contain `PUT` variables. I also stumbled upon the article from lornajane.net and tried it, now everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant access the data from a `PUT` request via `$_REQUEST`. You'd need something like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'PUT') {

    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$sent_vars);
    echo json_encode(['response'=>$sent_vars['id']]); // use an array and json_encode to avoid messy string concatenation 
}
```

See also [Accessing Incoming PUT Data from PHP](http://lornajane.net/posts/2008/accessing-incoming-put-data-from-php)

Answer (score 2):

So there are a couple of issues here:

1. PUT requests handle data parsing differently to POST, which is how you've formatted your request. So Delighted's response for more details.
2. You return a json string but don't convert it into a js object. You need something like `$.parseJSON(...)` for the object to return properly. So something like:

   ```
   success: function(responseData) {
       var r = $.parseJSON(responseData);
       console.log(r.response);
   }
   ```

Comment: JS object keys do not have to be quoted, the current implentation is valid. As for the response, just use `dataType: 'json',` and jQuery does the conversion for you, but indeed worth noting

Comment: Well blow me down. I had no idea jQuery could do that. My mistake on the first point though, I'll edit to reflect. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your help, very much appreciated!